Sending StreamContent and StringContent to API
Currently trying to send 2 images and a string to an API.
ApiCall:
var data = new
{
    mode = info
};

pathData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToString());

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    { new StreamContent(frontStream), "front", front.FullName },
    { new StreamContent(backStream), "back", back.FullName },
    { new StringContent(pathData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") }
};

using var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://localhost:987987987/Upload", content);

Tried using [FromBody] and I am still getting "Unsupported Media Type" response.
Api:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile front, IFormFile back, [FromBody] string mode)
{          
    return Ok();
}    

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

The "Unsupported Media Type" indicates that the API is not correctly interpreting the content being sent. This issue lies on how the data is being sent and how the API method is set up to receive them.
Some workarounds:

Correct the API method signature.
When using MultipartFormDataContent, you can not use [FromBody] for any parts of the request, as the data is sent as form-data, not as JSON in the body.
So you can do something like the above:

[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFromFile front,IFromFile back, [FromForm] string mode){
     if(front == null || back == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(mode)){
     return BadRequest("Invalid dataa");
}
//do what ever you want

return Ok();

}

2.Change client code. Make sure that client code sends the data correctly as MultipartFormDataContent.
Serialize mode as plain string:
The pathData serialization is incorrect since you are seializing data.ToString(), which returns a string representation of the object, Instead  directly use JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data):
var data = new {mode = info};
var pathData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

Adjust the MultipartFormDataContent:
Include the string content as a separate part of the form-data:
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent{
{new StreamContent(frontStream),"front", front.FullName},
{new StreamContent(frontStream),"back", back.FullName},
{new StringContent(info,Encoding.UTF8,"text/plain"),"mode"}

};
using var client = new HttpClient();
var resp = await client.PostAsync("url",content);


This was the answer I was looking for, the .ToString and the name on the StringContent did the trick. Thank you!

Unfortunately, I don't think both [FromBody] and [FromForm] can work together. Instead of sending the full object as "application/json", you should iterate each property in the data and append it as StringContent with the key to the MultipartFormDataContent.
string pathData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
Dictionary<string, dynamic> dataDict = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(pathData);

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    { new StreamContent(frontStream), "front", front.FullName },
    { new StreamContent(backStream), "back", back.FullName },
};

foreach (var prop in dataDict)
{
    content.Add(new StringContent(prop.Value), prop.Key);
}

using var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync($"https://localhost:987987987/Upload", content);

In your Upload API action, modify the method signature with the UploadModel as argument:
public class UploadModel
{
    public IFormFile Front { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Back { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("Upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] UploadModel model)
{          
    return Ok();
}


I didn't think this was necessary for just 3 parameters but I was able to implement this in another API call, thank you!

Adding the [Consumes("content-type")] defining the multipart/form-data as the content-type to your endpoint and removing the [FromBody] attribute from the mode parameter will fix this
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadRecipeImage(IFormFile front, IFormFile back, string mode)
{
    return Ok();
}

Related: How to set up a Web API controller for multipart/form-data
MS doc on Consumes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.consumesattribute?view=aspnetcore-9.0
